# Python: open file and show progress

Tags: python-3.x, binary

I do a simple

```
with open(window.filename, mode='rb') as file: # b is important -> binary
    fileContent = file.read()
```

and I want to show the progress of this open-process.. how would I do that? I mean, I can get the filesize first with

```
os.path.getsize(window.filename)
```

but what then? to what would i compare that value?

Answer (score 2):

You can use tqdm module for iterating over the size of your file in bytes and updating the progress in terminal using python

REF : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-how-to-make-a-terminal-progress-bar-using-tqdm/

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
      for i in tqdm(range(os.path.getsize("test.txt")), desc ="Text You Want"):
          f.read(10)
          sleep(.1)
```